# keep getting this error message when submitting, compiles fine, but marking software says its incorrect

Tags: java

we're meant to be making a moving bike, everything compiles but we keep getting this error message:

```
% java Main
== Benchmark program's output ==                     |  == Your program's output ==

The starting position of the bike is 0          |   0.0
Pedalling three times...                         |  471.23889803846896
The final position of the bike is 471                    <


The first line of output that differs is shown below:

< The starting position of the bike is 0
---
> 0.0
```

Comment: *we're meant to be making a moving bike* , show code please

Answer (score 1):

Read the instructions you're given more closely. You are expected to produce very specific output, and you're not doing that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are supposed to be formatting your output as integers (possibly with rounding, but check your assignment specs). Instead you are printing floating point output.

Answer (score 1):

Those numbers don't look **quite** the same to me.. I wonder what could cause that. (hint hint)